# Accidentally deleted /etc/paths

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, path, trash

I had recently messed up my $PATH variable so I thought if fixing it by removing the /etc/paths but I found out online solutions to fix the $PATH variable  by just editing the ~/.bash_profile so I moved the /etc/paths to the trash but then I accidentally emptied the trash so now its gone so now should I worry about some critical system apps to stop working if yes how should I fix this?

Comment: Restore from backup

Comment: I have backup of my home directory only.

Comment: Then reinstall the OS and set up a proper backup

Comment: But I don't think it's neceesary

Comment: True but it is the easiest and probably quickest way nowadays. It used to be reinstalling or restores took hours from tape. Now from time machine etc only a few minutes. Probably less time than you have spent on asking the question

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't have a huge disk I only have a 32GB sd card so I can't take backup of my pictures which is 20GB in size and 12 gigs of desktop files and apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/paths` file is used as an [initial value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356720) for the PATH variable. It should contain:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Its protection, owner and group should be:

```
-rw-r--r-- root wheel
```

`/etc/paths` is used by `/usr/libexec/path_helper` ... `man path_helper` says "default PATH and MANPATH values are obtained from the files /etc/paths and /etc/manpaths respectively." The file should exist so that PATH is set correctly.

Comment: But it is not necessary right?

Comment: Uh creidhne thanks for your reply I have added the paths file and there is a typo in your answer there are two /usr/bin so I replaced one of them as /bin.